# How to filter a list of strings?

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a list of strings that contain Non-English/English words. I want to filter out only English words.

Example:

```py
phrases = [
    "S/O अशोक कुमार, ब्लॉक न.-4डी, S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.",
    "स्ट्रीट-15, विभाग 5. सिविक सेंटर Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre",
    "भिलाई, दुर्ग, भिलाई, छत्तीसगढ़, Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,",
]
```

My code so far:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&()\\-`.+,/\"]+")
for i in phrases:
    print(regex.sub(' ', i))
```

My output:

```py
["S/O , .-4 , S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.",
  "-15, 5. Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre",
  ", , , , Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh",]
```

My desire output

```py
["S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.",
 "Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre",
 "Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,"]
```

Comment: It appears you have an unescaped `.` in you're regex expression which will match any character. If you want to match a period, it needs to be escaped, i.e. `\.`.  You should also look into special characters for regex, such as `\w` and `\d` which will make your expression shorter. It appears you want the matched strings to start with an english letter, so you could impose that match before going into the match of the rest of the string. e.g. `\w[\w\d]+`

Comment: @bicarlsen dots in groups don't need to be escaped, the issue is elsewhere

Comment: @bicarlsen, Hi Can you tell me what should be the expression ??

Comment: Thanks @mozway, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Beg you, however not to use regex for serious applications (e.g. _Adhaar Card_, _Banks_) because I have seen terrible mis-prints on IDs not in one but 20+ Indian languages. Better invest in special Unicode parsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I look at your data it seems you could use the following:

```
import regex as re
lst=["S/O अशोक कुमार, ब्लॉक न.-4डी, S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.",
      "स्ट्रीट-15, विभाग 5. सिविक सेंटर Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre",
      "भिलाई, दुर्ग, भिलाई, छत्तीसगढ़, Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,",]
for i in lst:
    print(re.sub(r'^.*\p{Devanagari}.+?\b', '', i))
```

Prints:

```
S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.
Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre
Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,
```

---

See an online regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FPslwa/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor;
- `.*\p{Devanagari}` - 0+ (Greedy) characters upto the last Devanagari letter;
- `.+?\b` - 1+ (Lazy) characters upto the first word-boundary

Comment: It is better to change `list` to something else since that way you overwriting that class.

Comment: @accdias, you are right

Comment: @JudV, any pointer to where `{Devanagari}`and other unicode languages are defined, I do a lot of scraping and this will save me lots of regexp lines

Comment: @MortenB, I find [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to be a great source of information.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you need with Python `re`, too.

**Solution 1**: You can remove all text from a non-ASCII letter to the *last* non-ASCII letter using

```py
import re
phrases = [ "S/O अशोक कुमार, ब्लॉक न.-4डी, S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.", "स्ट्रीट-15, विभाग 5. सिविक सेंटर Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre", "भिलाई, दुर्ग, भिलाई, छत्तीसगढ़, Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,", ]
rx = re.compile(r'[^\W\d_A-Za-z].*[^\W\d_A-Za-z]\W*')
l = [rx.sub('', text) for text in phrases]
print(l)
# => ['S/O S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.', 'Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre', 'Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,']
```

Here, `[^\W\d_A-Za-z].*[^\W\d_A-Za-z]\W*` matches a non-ASCII letter (`[^\W\d_A-Za-z]`), then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.*`), and then another non-ASCII letter and any zero or more non-word chars (`\W+`).

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/TlpTNI).

**Solution 2**: You may also remove all text from start till the last non-ASCII letter and all non-word chars from the string end with

```py
re.sub(r'.*[^\W\d_A-Za-z]\W*|\W+$', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pXuvgd/1). *Details*:

- `.*[^\W\d_A-Za-z]\W*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.*`) and then a non-ASCII letter (`[^\W\d_A-Za-z]`) and zero or more non-word chars (`\W*`)
- `|` - or
- `\W+$` - one or more non-word chars (`\W+`) at the end of the string (`$`).

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FMWMuQ):

```py
import re
phrases = [ "S/O अशोक कुमार, ब्लॉक न.-4डी, S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.", "स्ट्रीट-15, विभाग 5. सिविक सेंटर Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre", "भिलाई, दुर्ग, भिलाई, छत्तीसगढ़, Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,", ]
rx = re.compile(r'.*[^\W\d_A-Za-z]\W*|\W+$')
l = [rx.sub('', text) for text in phrases]
print(l)
# => ['S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D', 'Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre', 'Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that your characters may only be of standard english letters and your regex works for that and you only want to filter out the problematic ", , , ," values you could do something like this:

```
def format_output(current_output):
    results = []
    for row in current_output:
        # split on the ","
        sub_elements = row.split(",").
        # this will leave the empty ones as "" in the list which can be filtered
        filtered = list(filter(key=lambda x: len(x) > 0, sub_elements))
        # then join the elements togheter and append to the final results array
        results.append(",".join(filtered))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the first part of each element of the list is the Hindi translation of the second part and there is a one-to-one correspondence between the number of words.

So for the example that you've provided and any that follow the exact same pattern(it will break if it does not), all you have to do is take the second part of each element of the array.

```
phrases = ["S/O अशोक कुमार, ब्लॉक न.-4डी, S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.",
  "स्ट्रीट-15, विभाग 5. सिविक सेंटर Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre",
  "भिलाई, दुर्ग, भिलाई, छत्तीसगढ़, Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,",]


mod_list = []
for s in list:
    tmp_list = []
    strg = s.split()
    n = len(strg)
    for i in range(int(n/2),n):
        tmp_list.append(strg[i])
    tmp_list = ' '.join(tmp_list)
    mod_list.append(tmp_list)

print(mod_list)
```

Output:

```
['S/O Ashok Kumar, Block no.-4D.', 
'Street-15, sector -5, Civic Centre', 
'Bhilai, Durg. Bhilai, Chhattisgarh,']
```

Comment: It is better to change `list` to something else since that way you overwriting that class.